# NSDictionary sorted by array value?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *sort = @{@"key1": @[@"one", @"two"],
                        @"key2": @[@"o", @"t", @"p"]};
```

And i want sorting him by array.count.
While decided to use sorting bubble, followed by the addition of elements std::map since he ordered.
But maybe there are some standard solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can sort the keys within the dictionary, however if you want an array of the keys in order based on the count of their value arrays you can do something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(NSArray *obj1, NSArray *obj2) {
            if (obj1.count > obj2.count) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
            if (obj1.count < obj2.count) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];
```

Then once you have the keys in order you can iterate through them like this:

```
for (NSString *key in sortedKeysArray) {
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:key]
    // Do something now that you have the arrays in order from smallest to largest
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, NSOrderedDescending works fine, but NSOrderedAscending, sorts incorrectly.

Comment: what's happening exactly?